# Kubernetes Container Failing and stuck in CrashLoopBackOff status with no events/logs in pods

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, azure-aks

My container in Kubernetes is failing and stuck in CrashLoopBackOff state with no logs/events to track the error.

[image]

Above screenshot is taken through Azure Kubernets Extensions on VS Code
There is no visible logs for me to further investigate the issue.

In Container description, it says it's terminated due to exit code 134.
[image]

What does this error code mean? and where can I find the logs for container termination?

Comment: Is it dotnet application?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu Yes

Comment: Are you connecting to database from the application? What does kubectl get events say? Try to describe the pod kubectl describe pod podname and try to get logs kubectl get logs podname --previous

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I am not connected to any database from the application. Kubctl get events say it backed off restarting failed container.

describe pod shows the same message as events, and get logs does not return any thing :/ I'm assuming it didn't event get to start before backing off..?

Comment: What image do you use to deploy in the Kubernetes? Does the image run well locally? And do you use AKS?